# Simplexml_load_string doesn't load everything

Tags: php, xml, arrays, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I want to load all xml values into array

for example, i've the following xml

```
<rating>
<kp_rating num_vote="14008">8.665</kp_rating>
<imdb_rating num_vote="94758">8.8</imdb_rating>
</rating>
```

using Simplexml_load_string i'm getting only

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [kp_rating] => 8.665 [imdb_rating] => 8.8 )
```

How can I get in addition the `num_vote`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the node attributes using the array access syntax:

```
$xml->kp_rating['num_vote']
$xml->imdb_rating['num_vote']
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5429):

> SimpleXML can also access element attributes. Access attributes of an element just as you would elements of an [array](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php).